# Making urls work with a preventdefault - JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Here is my html links, I would like to handle (show , hide ) and the linking, making my urls work

```
    <ul class="menu" id="menu-lateral"><li class="subLevel"><a href="#"><span>Logiciels de Gestion &amp; ERP </span></a><br><ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;"><li><a href="logiciels-gestion-commerciale" title="Logiciels Gestion commerciale"><span>&gt; Logiciels Gestion commerciale</span></a></li>
<li><a href="logiciels-planning" title="Logiciels Planning"><span>&gt; Logiciels Planning</span></a></li>
<li><a href="logiciels-comptabilite" title="Logiciels Comptabilité"><span>&gt; Logiciels Comptabilité</span></a></li>
<li><a href="logiciels-paie-rh" title="Logiciels Paie et RH"><span>&gt; Logiciels Paie et&nbsp;RH</span></a></li>
<li><a href="logiciels-dessins-metres" title=""><span>&gt; Logiciels Dessins et métrés</span></a></li>
<li><a href="solutions-erp-pgi-batiment" title="Solutions ERP et PGI Bâtiment"><span>&gt; Solutions&nbsp;ERP et PGI</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subLevel"><a href="infrastructure-reseaux" title="Infrastructure Réseaux"><span>Infrastructure &amp; réseaux</span></a><br><ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;"><li><a href="materiel-informatique" title="Matériel informatique"><span>&gt; Matériel informatique</span></a></li>
<li><a href="securite-reseaux" title="Sécurité des réseaux"><span>&gt; Sécurité des réseaux</span></a></li>
<li><a href="gestion-de-sites-distants" title="Gestion de sites distants"><span>&gt; Gestion de sites distants</span></a></li>
<li><a href="virtualisation" title="Virtualisation"><span>&gt; Virtualisation</span></a></li>
<li><a href="messagerie-hebergee" title="Messagerie hébergée"><span>&gt; Messagerie hébergée</span></a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="subLevel"><a href="site-web-vitrine" title="site-web-vitrine"><span>Site web</span></a></li>
<li class="subLevel"><a href="formation-logiciels" title="Formation Logiciels"><span>Formation logiciels</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And javascript is here :

```
$('#menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default

            $('#menu-lateral li a').click(function(e) {
              //  e.preventDefault();
                $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
            });
```

Comment: And the problem is?  What is happening/not happen that should be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default
$('#menu-lateral li a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') { // if href is not # then go link
        return true;
    } else { // if href is '#' then show the sub menu
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwQQ/3/)

Comment: This is very awesome. Thank you. As you can see it's working for the first level and not for the second ! Dou you have any idea

Comment: because it has href as url path